# Why can't I resize the columns of Fluent UI's DetailsList component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, detailslist

I created a react app with 'npx create-react-app'. I installed the npm package by running 'npm i @fluentui/react'. I implemented the DetailsList component of Fluent UI in my App.js:

```js
import "./App.css";
import { DetailsList } from "@fluentui/react";

function App() {
  const columns = [
    {
      key: "column1",
      name: "Name",
      fieldName: "name",
      minWidth: 100,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: true,
    },
    {
      key: "column2",
      name: "Value",
      fieldName: "value",
      minWidth: 100,
      maxWidth: 200,
      isResizable: true,
    },
  ];
  const items = [
    { key: 1, name: "good", value: 1 },
    { key: 2, name: "bad", value: 2 },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DetailsList items={items} columns={columns} setKey="set" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can see the list properly but I can't resize the columns. Even though I set 'isResizable: true' for every column. Why? How can I make them resizable. Btw: unlike the Fluent UI documentation, I want to use functional components (I hope this isn't the problem).

Comment: You need to provide `isResizable: true` if you want to resize column. Here you are the implementation: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsHeader.base.tsx#L617 . Some of FluentUI Components are implemented as Class Components, but it's totally fine to wrap them with your custom FP component for abstraction...

Comment: @MarkoSavic I already provided isResizable: true in both columns and I still can't resize them.

Comment: Remove maxWidth its unnecessary. If that doesn't work create codepen example to see whats going on.

Comment: Details list column headers currently aren't resizable when React.StrictMode is applied (which  is the default in `create-react-app`).  See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/27166), and note that this should only be an issue in the dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

- I updated office-ui-fabric-react "7.202.0" from "7.156.0".
- Imported IColumn from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react" instead of just "office-ui-fabric-react"

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found the answer in this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/15786#issuecomment-722688124)

In a nutshell, in the `DetailsList` Component you are missing the following attribute `layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns}`. This attribute lets the user resize the columns marked as resizible.

Here is the code example from the gitHub issue:

```
<DetailsList
          items={['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','']}
          columns={columns}
          selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
          layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns}
          constrainMode={ConstrainMode.unconstrained}
          isHeaderVisible={true}
        />
```

Hope this helps!